# Question about java executeables?

Tags: java

If i have a very simple program say consisting of only a single .class file, how can i run it on some other computer. I mean i can run it using java filename, but point is i have jdk installed.

So how about someone, who does not have jdk and want to test out my class file. Is there any other way to do it for it to run without jdk. If it is not possible, then i don't find any benefit of using java, or is there any?

Comment: ~90% of computers have a JRE.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the *JDK* to run Java, you simply need the [JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), which almost all computers [have](http://javatester.org/version.html).

Comment: so on those systems, how am i suppose to run it.
Like through command prompt in which directory should i go?

Comment: Neither Windows 7, Vista, XP SP3 or even Ubuntu ship with a JRE installed by default.

Comment: @Steve: Fair enough, so don't install any of those ;).

Comment: Im sorry but can someone guide me here.
for a novice user, who is to run my program, the java which you can install by default from java.com would be enough or is to get something special to get it working?

Comment: @Sara yes - the Java from java.com is enough to run Java (it is the JRE).

Comment: thanks, so what i understood is that anyone with standard JRE can run java or javaw command at command line, provided her environment variables are properly set.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your java program in a launcher, such as http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

if JRE not detected in the system, the launcher will ask user to download the JRE, or you can also provide bundled JRE in the package of program you distribute.

If it is really simple program, try compiling it using GCJ into native executable format.
For windows, you can use MinGW gcj http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Compile_with_gcj

Executable from GCJ doesn't need JRE or JDK to launch, but might need some library (.dll or .so) to be distribute together with your executable.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your class name is HelloWorld. Open command prompt, navigate to the directory in which your HelloWorld.class is placed, type "java HelloWorld" and hit enter. Check out this [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html) as well for a step-by-step tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JDK to test your Java .class JRE is enough

http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=46223

The "JDK" is the Java Development Kit. I.e., the JDK is bundle of software that you can use to develop Java based software. The "JRE" is the Java Runtime Environment. I.e., the JRE is an implementation of the Java Virtual Machine which actually executes Java programs.